# FacebookSdk not starting android

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x, android-runtime

I have tried everything from tutorials, answers all around, even with examples from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/samples. I have tried with test app and normal app in developers.facebook.com/apps

But i always get this error
A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.

Full error:

> 

```
05-31 22:19:09.798 2895-2895/jonjon.fb1 I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-31 22:19:09.868 2895-2895/jonjon.fb1 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/jonjon.fb1-1/lib/x86_64
05-31 22:19:09.888 2895-2895/jonjon.fb1 I/FacebookInitProvider: Failed to auto initialize the Facebook SDK
                                                                A valid Facebook app id must be set in the AndroidManifest.xml or set by calling FacebookSdk.setApplicationId before initializing the sdk.
                                                                    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:275)
                                                                    at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:231)
                                                                    at com.facebook.internal.FacebookInitProvider.onCreate(FacebookInitProvider.java:20)
                                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
05-31 22:19:09.892 2895-2895/jonjon.fb1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                          --------- beginning of crash
05-31 22:19:09.892 2895-2895/jonjon.fb1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: jonjon.fb1, PID: 2895
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider: 500: Initialization error: 502: The App Id must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                           Caused by: 500: Initialization error: 502: The App Id must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.getRequiredString(Initializer.java:228)
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.initialize(Initializer.java:113)
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.initialize(AccountKitController.java:592)
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider.onCreate(AccountKitInitProvider.java:31)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
05-31 22:41:18.585 3969-3969/jonjon.fb1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-31 22:41:18.585 3969-3969/jonjon.fb1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: jonjon.fb1, PID: 3969
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider: 500: Initialization error: 503: The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5156)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                           Caused by: 500: Initialization error: 503: The Client Token must be specified in the string resource file as com.facebook.accountkit.ClientToken
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.getRequiredString(Initializer.java:228)
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.Initializer.initialize(Initializer.java:118)
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitController.initialize(AccountKitController.java:592)
                                                              at com.facebook.accountkit.internal.AccountKitInitProvider.onCreate(AccountKitInitProvider.java:31)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                              at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //initialize Facebook SDK
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }
```

Comment: I know this is from months ago but are you adding this into androidmanifest?

Comment: On Manifest you should add the app id data, this code should be implemented on the activity you're using the Facebook login with.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialize Facebook SDK
 FacebookSdk.setClientToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        FacebookSdk.setIsDebugEnabled(true);
        FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    } }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It fails to initialize the library.
I think the solution as said in the logcat is to add a string in strings.xml with the name

> com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId

As value you must put the token
Then you can call

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
```

In onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Since  `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());` is deprecated. You can use these methods to initialize facebookSDK

```
FacebookSdk.fullyInitialize();
AppEventsLogger.activateApp(application);
```

It works fine